# How to find user coordinates in Yandex Map kit?

Tags: android, yandex, yandex-mapkit

How to find user coordinates in YandexMapkit?

I use the Location class and prescribe

```
private Location location;
location.getPosition();
```

but it is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should look at the repository: https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-ios-demo - there are a lot of useful samples. 
Here is how I do if I want to get user location in iOS app:

```
    let mapKit = YMKMapKit.sharedInstance()
    let userLocationLayer = mapKit.createUserLocationLayer(with: mapView.mapWindow)
    userLocationLayer.setVisibleWithOn(true)
    userLocationLayer.isHeadingEnabled = true
```

mapView - is YMKMapView! from storyboard.

Of course you should also ask permissions from user and add to info.plist "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description".